# 503 Service Unavailable on every post request on my shared hosting

Tags: laravel, hosting, shared

Can someone please help me with my problem im struggeling with for the past day.

It all worked normal a few days ago, but since yesterday everytime i try to send a contact form or i try to login my cms

i get this errorlog

"Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Additionally, a 304 Not Modified error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Im working with a Laravel project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r0i7.png)

I've tried to install composer again but that didnt workout

Comment: 503 tends to mean "the server is overloaded" on shared hosting. File a ticket with your provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error HTTP 503 service unavailable occurs due to the following reasons.

1. IF the web server is not available or down.
2. IF servers resources(RAM, CPU) get to high.
3. If there is an attack on the site.

To resolve this, first, you can reboot the server, so if resources get high, it can be normal again for some time, and you can find if there is an attack on the site.

Also, you can check the event-viewers log if the IIS service is unavailable or get the causing issue-related log from the event viewer.

The error HTTP 304 Not Modified indicates that the requested resources have not been modified since the last time you accessed them (Web page files etc...).

Generally, Search engines such as google, yahoo are responsible for indexing and caching websites. So this issue can usually be traced back to the browser used to access the site.

Below are the methods you can use to resolve this.

1. Clear the Browser’s Cache Data
2. Run a Malware Scan
3. Disable Your Browser’s Extensions
4. Flush the DNS and Reset the TCP/IP
5. Try Using the Google Public DNS
6. Check Your Server Configuration Files for Incorrect Redirect Instructions

Hope this will help ;)

Comment: Did you read the entire message? The Reset of the TCP/IP is for  HTTP 304, not for 503. CHECK THE ENTIRE SOLUTION.

Comment: Again, explain what "reset the TCP/IP" means. What exactly do you want OP to do, and why would it help the message about a 304? The 304 message is a server-side bit from the Apache webserver, which can't find a valid `ErrorDocument` to serve for the 503; resetting something on OP's computer won't do anything. I read the entire "solution", it's just not a solution.

Comment: The point Flush the DNS and Reset the TCP/IP It's about resetting TCP/IP in chrome,  

To flush your DNS. To do so, you can enter “chrome://net-internals/#dns” into your browser’s search bar and then hit the Enter key:

The option to flush your DNS via Chrome.

Next, click on the Clear host cache button located under the DNS tab. Once you’re done, try restarting your browser to re-access the URL.

Again it's valid solution